# lightning:formattedDateTime changes the date

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

When I use the lightning:formattedDateTime in lightning component with a date field and formatting with "numeric", it displays a different value from the field. I use the following line of code:

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!task.due_date}" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" />
```

And the due_date field, that is a Date only and holds the value "4/24/2018", displays the value "4/23/2018" on the page. But if I use the code without specifying the format, it displays the right value, but not in the format I want (displays "Apr 24, 2018").

Someone knows what can be done to display the right value in the numeric format? I do not want to specify the time zone because it has to display in user's time zone.

Comment: Allowed values for the month attribute are 2-digit, narrow, short, or long. Have you tried one of those and see how it looks? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_formattedDateTime.htm

Comment: If `task.due_date` is a DateTime, then you need to add `timeZone="{! $Locale.timezone }"` to get the timezone handled correctly. Think not needed if it's a Date though.

Comment: @KeithC the 'task.due_date' is a Date, but even so, worked like a charm! Thank you!

Comment: @KeithC Care to post that information as an `Answer` proper?

Comment: Why isn't `timeZone="{!$Locale.timezone}"` default?  Strange...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you @KeithC! Even the `task.due_date` being a Date field, putting the code `timeZone="{! $Locale.timezone }` works and the timezone is handled correctly!

Comment: Common etiquette on the forum would be to add a comment where you `@mention` the person who gave you the answer, prompting them to post an answer so you can properly recognize/reward their assistance.

Comment: @AdrianLarson sorry, actually I've tried to mention him, but it didn't work. Could you try to so Keith C post the answer so I can mark as solved?

Comment: Fair point. I'll just bump that in the comments. Don't forget to accept this answer if he never gets back to you!

Comment: I had a similar issue with the date being incorrect when passing a date value to a column of type 'date' on the lightining:datatable component (which renders a lightning:formattedDateTime component behind the scenes). Unfortunately passing the timezone from the locale didn't work, but manually passing 'UTC' as the timezone value made the dates appear correctly.

Comment: @Mike Topalovich: If you are working in lightning:datatable, and if you want to display the value on date column irrespective of user's locale timezone, you can use type: 'date-local' while defining the column for date in lightning:datatable