# A Posted Solution to a lightning:formattedDateTime Problem No Longer Works

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, date, timezone, aura-attribute

I have the same problem asked about [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/216032/lightningformatteddatetime-changes-the-date), where the date displayed by the `lightning:formattedDateTime` component does not match the *date* field that's its  value.

I attempted the answer chosen in the original post, which is to add `timeZone="{!$Locale.timezone}"`, like so:

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.application.Seat_Deposit_Due_Date__c}" year="numeric" month="short" day="2-digit" weekday="long" timeZone="{!$Locale.timezone}"/>
```

But the date is still incorrect; one day less than the field's date.

I also tried the poster's set of attributes and values like below, but the date remained off.

```
<lightning:formattedDateTime value="{!v.application.Seat_Deposit_Due_Date__c}" year="numeric" month="numeric" day="numeric" timeZone="{!$Locale.timezone}"/>
```

Am I missing something to make the original answer work in my case?  Or is there a new solution?

Comment: what the org's timezone and whats the running user's timezone?

Comment: The same:  (GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/New_York)

Comment: if you just print `{!v.application.Seat_Deposit_Due_Date__c}` what value do you get?

Comment: `{!v.application.Seat_Deposit_Due_Date__c}`:  2020-01-24.  Through `lightning:formattedDateTime`:  Thursday, Jan 23, 2020

Comment: I tried `<lightning:formattedDateTime value="2020-01-24" year="numeric"
                                 month="short" day="2-digit" weekday="long"  />` by changing my user and org timezone to `(GMT-05:00) Eastern Standard Time (America/New_York)` and properly print `Friday, 24 Jan 2020`

Comment: At some point in the day the dates catch up to each other.  I checked the dates after your comment and they matched.  I checked them this morning and they once again do not match.